# nobody & nonroot user in distroless images

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, privileges, distroless

[Distroless images](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless) comes with 3 users :

```
> docker run --rm --entrypoint cat gcr.io/distroless/nodejs:debug /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/sbin/nologin
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/sbin/nologin
nonroot:x:65532:65532:nonroot:/home/nonroot:/sbin/nologin
```

If you run the image without a `USER` instruction in your **Dockerfile** the image runs as **uid=0(root) gid=0(root)**.

I would like to avoid this and use an unprivileged user.

Other than **nobody** not having a `/home` directory, what is the difference between using `USER nobody` and `USER nonroot` in my Dockerfile ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 type of distroless images which can be used in production:

*with latest tag*
This image say, `gcr.io/distroless/base` by default has "Config.User: 0" and "Config.WorkingDir: /" config in it and if you don't use `USER` for switching the user to `nonroot` user which is defined in it or it will start container with `root` user.

*with nonroot tag*
This image say, `gcr.io/distroless/base:nonroot` by default has "Config.User: 65532" and "Config.WorkingDir: /home/nonroot" config in it and there is no need to use `USER` for changing user to non-root user.
PS: maybe you need to change ownership of copied files in multistage build to `nonroot` user.

**nobody user**
The purpose of `nobody` user is not related to distroless images and it's about Linux itself which described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/329716/459993) very well